# asp dropdownlist not getting proper value

Tags: asp.net

i am populating my dropdown in this manner on page load.(The stringbuilder is there just to prove that the right list items were retrieved)

The dropdown selected event ALWAYS retrieves an index of 0, no matter what item I select from the list, which leads me to believe that something is wrong with how i am populating the dropdwonlist AND the selected value is always the value associated with the item that is first in the list when the dropdown appears on page load, no matter what item is selected from the dropdown.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Using ctx As New dbentities()
        Try
            Dim query = (From c In ctx.my_aspnet_users Select c.name, c.id).ToList()

            ddlSiteUsers.DataSource = query
            ddlSiteUsers.DataTextField = "name"
            ddlSiteUsers.DataValueField = "id"
            ddlSiteUsers.DataBind()
            'For Each item As ListItem In ddlSiteUsers.Items
            '    sb.Append(item)
            '    sb.Append(",")
            '    sb.Append(item.Value)
            '    sb.Append(";" & vbCrLf)
            'Next
            'MsgBox(sb.ToString())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Page_Load()` event fires when the page initially loads, and also when you postback the page.

This means that, before your click/indexchanged event fires, it's re-running the code in your `Page_Load()` when you submit the form.

To stop this, you need to put an `if` statement around your code so that it only populates the dropdown list when the page initially loads (i.e. when not posting back)

e.g.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then 
    'Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Using ctx As New dbentities()
      Try
        Dim query = (From c In ctx.my_aspnet_users Select c.name, c.id).ToList()

        ddlSiteUsers.DataSource = query
        ddlSiteUsers.DataTextField = "name"
        ddlSiteUsers.DataValueField = "id"
        ddlSiteUsers.DataBind()
        'For Each item As ListItem In ddlSiteUsers.Items
        '    sb.Append(item)
        '    sb.Append(",")
        '    sb.Append(item.Value)
        '    sb.Append(";" & vbCrLf)
        'Next
        'MsgBox(sb.ToString())
      Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.StackTrace.ToString())
      End Try
    End Using
  End If
End Sub
```